# How to deactivate Spring Data exception translation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

The new `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator` uses a fallthrough in the sense that it first tries to map the exception using vanilla Hibernate (`SessionFactoryUtils`). If no translation could be done it tries JPA via `EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible()`.

The latter troubles us as it is translating `IllegalStateException` to  `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException`. I'm not really sure why   `IllegalStateException` and `IllegalArgumentException` get this special treatment, but ok. So now we suddenly end up with translated exceptions that weren't translated before. Since these extra translations are in context of JPA (as it is called `convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible`) this also makes no sense as we are not using JPA but vanilla Hibernate.

So, what is the correct way to make sure that we only get Hibernate exceptions translated? Afaic the `HibernateExceptionTranslator` has no options to turn off JPA translation and the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` extends `HibernateExceptionTranslator` without the option to inject another implementation. Wouldn't it make more sense to have the `HibernateExceptionTranslator` JPA unaware and add another translator in case JPA is actually used?

Answer (score 2):

From Spring Data [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/):

> Using this element looks up Spring Data repositories as described in
>   Creating repository instances. Beyond that it activates persistence
>   exception translation for all beans annotated with @Repository to let
>   exceptions being thrown by the JPA persistence providers be converted
>   into Spring’s DataAccessException hierarchy.

Omit the @Repository annotation, then vanilla Hibernate exceptions won't get translated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14681 for the appropriate answer(s)