# CannotAcquireLockException + LockAcquisitionException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I am investigating an issue I have in my Spring Data + Hibernate app. I have found the issue in the logs but I am trying to understand why a hibernate exception `org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException` can throw a Spring `org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException`?

For exception reporting, I would like my exceptions to be consistent and to throw all Hibernate exceptions. Is this possible?

```
Caught unhandled exceptionorg.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not update: [com.database.model.MyTable#22791]; SQL [update MyTable set x=1, etc]; nested exception is
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not update:[com.database.model.MyTable#22791]#  at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)#   at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)#  at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)# at
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTr
```

Answer (score 0):

> why a hibernate exception `org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException` can throw a Spring `org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException`?

It doesn't. The hibernate exception gets caught and then a Spring exception gets thrown.

> For exception reporting, I would like my exceptions to be consistent and to throw all Hibernate exceptions. Is this possible?

I'm not sure I understand why this would be more consistent than logging Spring exceptions or actually beneficial at all. All exceptions inherit from `Throwable` which offers access to its cause, which should be properly set for all Spring exceptions that are caused by other exceptions. So you can certainly navigate the the chain of causes to find the exception that you want to log. You might even find some of the methods in the various Spring Exceptions helpful, for example [getMostSpecificCause](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException.html#getMostSpecificCause--).

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate's LockAcquisitionException does not throw Spring's CannotAcquireLockException. Any Spring repository annotated with @Repository, which I believe Spring Data repositories innately are, will come with Spring exception translation. This is so your data layer does not leak out and is all wrapped by common Spring exceptions. See Spring's javadocs on PersistenceExceptionTranslator class or on exception translation.

To disable the translation maybe see this thread: [How to deactivate Spring Data exception translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393116/how-to-deactivate-spring-data-exception-translation)